# Which screenshot software can write the "data taken" information of a screenshot?

Tags: windows, open-source, screenshot

Amazon photo seems using the information of "date taken" for　odering uploaded photos. For also saving my screenshots with order, I would like to know: is there any free or open source software **can write the "data taken" information (which likes contained a camera shotted photo) when taking a screenshot**? Thanks.

###### Tested

I have tested ShareX, Lightshot and Greenshot; but seems that they do not have this function. Windows's Snipping tool has this function, however without shortcuts and thus not so convenient for me.

Answer (score 2):

I get a partial answer from [ShareX's solution on GitHub](https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX/issues/5852#issuecomment-931891463):

> I have tried add `date taken` for jpg using `exiftool` as follows.
>
> ```
> exiftool -overwrite_original  '-DateTimeOriginal<FileCreateDate' DIR
> ```
>
> Thus one trick for doing the task using `ShareX` is through `After capture tasks -> Perform action`, with `exiftool` and arguments as follows.
>
> ```
> "-overwrite_original"  "-DateTimeOriginal<FileCreateDate" "$input"
> ```
>
> However, I also hope ShareX can do this in default.